# AdMob Native Ads

Tags: ios, firebase, ads, admob

I would like to display ads inside my freemium iOS app and would like to use AdMobs Native Ads to better match the style of my app. But now I have three questions regarding those Ads...

From what I’ve read they are currently limited?!?

> Native Ads Advanced is currently in a limited beta release. If you are interested in participating, reach out to your account manager.

See. https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/native-advanced

So will I able to display those? At least I am currently receiving some test-ads right now... And if so, when live, are there enough Ads to show?

Second question is regarding that little (i) Icon. The one for privacy policies. I just can’t manage to set it to a different position...
As far as I think its the `adChoicesView`, right? And the documentation states:

> Must set adChoicesView before setting nativeAppInstallAd, otherwise AdChoices will be rendered in the publisher's preferredAdChoicesPosition as defined in GADNativeAdViewAdOptions.

So inside my Ad-View I have a UIView which class I did set to `GADAdChoicesView` and that one is set before I set the Ad on my `GADNativeAppInstallAd`... but still, it will render it’s own (i) symbol. How can I set the position of that Icon myself?

Furthermore... On one screen, a very small part of the Ad would be covered by a UI-Element. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "So will I able to display those? At least I am currently receiving some test-ads right now... And if so, when live, are there enough Ads to show?"

Yes, you will be able to display these ads, but you would need to talk to google account manager.

We tried but they need your app to have substantial number(more than 100000 maybe) of users , so you should try contacting.

> "How can I set the position of that Icon myself?"
>   In java there are properties like

```
    ADCHOICES_TOP_LEFT

    ADCHOICES_TOP_RIGHT

    ADCHOICES_BOTTOM_RIGHT

    ADCHOICES_BOTTOM_LEFT
```

So there must be something like these in ios.

Also try to follow all the guidelines, as google tends to block account as they consider that to be illegal clicks. Check out the link for more details

[Admob Support](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6128543?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Will try to figure out how to ready one of those account managers :) Not that easy on first sight :)

Comment: About the positioning... I'd like to position it to an exact position where it nicely aligns with other content...

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but regarding the positioning I think you can use Swift's (or Objc-C's) NSLayoutConstraints. A Swift example in your case is:

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            adChoises.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            adChoises.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            adChoises.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            adChoises.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
        ])
```

leadingAnchor means "left" and trailingAnchor means "right".

Comment: I would have added this as a comment since it only partly answers your question, but it wasn't possible because it became too long for a comment and I couldn't use the code view. It just didn't make any sense as a comment. I hope it helps someone =)